# Re Auditing tables in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a stored procedure which initiates the process by calling a `BATCH_ID`, so in informatica I don't want to call the stored procedure for initiating Batch_ID, Is there any best practice for initializing the batch_id and insert the values into audit table

Comment: It's really hard to tell how your process looks like, how do you use and what actually is the BATCH_ID. It would help if you'd describe the process and your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a pre-process to insert a row into audit table.

Based on your use case if you provide more details, we can add to this.